# How can I make location-based spells which create soil patches on the ground?

Tags: skyrim-modding

I'm making a spell that'll place a soil patch on the ground in skyrim, and I cannot get it to work. I would like some help. When I tested the spell in game, no soil patch appeared on the ground. I tried doing it on different terrains and different levels of hills, mountains, etc. with no luck. I'm not sure what I am missing. I'm using the soil patches that are functional in the HearthFire DLC.

Here is what I've done thus far:

I made an activator "marker" with a script attached to it that is supposed to summon a soil patch at its location. This is the current script for it:

> ```
> ScriptName maSpawnSoilPatchActivatorScript Extends ObjectReference  
>
> ObjectReference refMarkerPosition
>
> Event OnInit()
>
>    refMarkerPosition = Self.PlaceAtMe(Game.GetForm(0x02008240))
>
> EndEvent
> ```

[image]

After, I made a "dummy" explosion that is supposed to place the activator at the location where the spell hits, so that it can spawn the soil patch in that location.

[image]

I then added the dummy explosion to a new magic effect, and then attached the magic effect to the conjuration spell I created.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`PlaceAtMe`](http://www.creationkit.com/PlaceAtMe_-_ObjectReference) to place your soil patch in the *magic effect*, rather than in the activator.

I have teleport spell to teleport me to my created world which works fine if the script is placed in the magic effect section rather than the activator. Try that.